# Dart question about concatenating objects and strings

Tags: dart

How can I concatenate a string "km/h" to the print(tesla.speed);  ? So that the console will output 200 km/h ? I know the easy way to do it is by changing the "int? speed" to "String? speed" and then putting the km/h into the topSpeed: "200km/h". But I want to know if there's a specifically another way to do it without changing int? speed to String? speed.  ?

```
void main() {
  Car tesla = Car(carModel: "Model-S", topSpeed: 200);

  print (tesla.model);
  print (tesla.speed);
}


class Car{

  String? model;
  int? speed;

  Car({String? carModel, int? topSpeed}){
    model = carModel;
    speed = topSpeed;
  }
}
```

Comment: `'${tesla.speed} km/h'`

Comment: Kishan Dhankecha answer it in answer section I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: Sure. I will do that with little explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To do this you have to add a dollar sign in front of the variable name in String as below.

```dart
String name = "John Doe";

print('Good Morning, $name');
```

#### In the above example, we used a direct variable as an input in string. However, In your case, you used a Modal class to store data. So we can't just do string manipulation as `'$name'`. This will print `Instance of 'Car'`. For this situation, we have to add curly braces around the object we need to add in string interpolation as below.

```dart
Car tesla = Car(carModel: "Model-S", topSpeed: 200);

print ('${tesla.speed} km/h');
```

For more info see this:

[image: Demonstration of string interpolation in dart]

> [source](https://github.com/course-zero/getting-started-with-dart/blob/master/C.arithmetics-and-string-interpolation/2.string-interpolation.dart)

Answer (score 0):

I think your print content change same as:

```
print('${speed} km/h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unit as a separate entity in Car object itself.

```
void main() {
  Car tesla = Car(carModel: "Model-S", topSpeed: 200, speedUnit : "km/h");

  print(tesla.model);
  print('${tesla.speed} ${tesla.unit}');
}


class Car {
  String? model;
  int? speed;
  String? unit;

  Car({String? carModel, int? topSpeed, String? speedUnit}) {
    model = carModel;
    speed = topSpeed;
    unit = speedUnit;

  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).